# How to integrate Google Pay?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment, android-pay, google-pay

I want to integrate Google Pay in my android application. I have tried [this](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) repo. getting the following error.

> This merchant is not enabled for google pay

Here is some of my code which is causing the error.

```
public static final HashMap<String, String> PAYMENT_GATEWAY_TOKENIZATION_PARAMETERS = new HashMap<String, String>() {

   put("gateway", "example"); // WHAT SHOULD I WIRTE INSTED OF EXAMPLE?
          put("gatewayMerchantId", "MerchantIdexample"); //found from https://merchants.google.com 
          // Your processor may require additional parameters.
        }
};
```

Comment: The error explains clearly that you need to open a merchant account in google pay.

Comment: i have already opened and verified merchant account in google pay

Comment: I think you should have a merchant id which needs to be put in the code. Did you do that as well?

Comment: yes, i have already done that. any other settings ?
 // WHAT SHOULD I WIRTE INSTED OF EXAMPLE
i have written merchant name, is it ok?

Comment: now i face **unexpected developer**  error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your manifest (inside application)::

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
out_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Progress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>  

Java
```

Comment: I think you're just dumped your clipboard in this comment

Answer (score -3):

the transaction may be risky. For your safety, it cant be completed at this time I am also getting this error while using this code

```
      </a>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer. Please check on how to write awesome answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer